# how do you set autogroup triggers on no file buffers?

Tags: vim

I'm using a plugin which always creates a buffer named "[Scratch]" whenever I use omnicomplete. I want to hide this. I tried doing this:

```
au BufNew [Scratch] bunload
```

However, this never gets triggered. I believe that is because the pattern is matching against the filename and not the buffer name. Is there a way to to change this behavior?

EDIT:

Never mind, the option I wanted was

```
set completeopt = menu,menuone,longest
```

This gets rid of the scratch buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the wrong approach.

Instead I'll look into the (omnicomplete?) plugin you are using to see if there is an option to disable the creation of that scratch buffer. If not, contact the plugin's author to ask him to add this option.